# Adding xml attribute to property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I have some class,fox example

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string SomeProperty{get;set;}
}
```

When I serialize object of this class,I get

```
    <test>
        <SomeProperty>value<someproperty>
    <test>
```

But I need add attribute to SomeProperty **without changing structure of class** and get this

```
    <test>
      <SomeProperty Search="true">value<someproperty>
    <test>
```

How can I do that?

PS:I know,that i can write object that include "SomeProperty" and Bool property "Search",but it will change structure of class

Comment: And how/where is the value of `Search` stored with the instance of Test?

Comment: This is a question.May be some attribute exists

Comment: And maybe not. Better take a few steps back and ask about what you really need to do. This seems halfway down a failed solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm pretty sure that indeed it *does not*

Answer (score 2):

To do that with `XmlSerializer`, you would need to have a second type with an `[XmlAttribute]` an `[XmlText]`. The only other option is `IXmlSerializable`, which is: a lot of work and easy to get wrong.

Options:

- change the structure of `SomeProperty`
- add a *shim* property *in parallel* with `SomeProperty` - and mark `SomeProperty` as `[XmlIgnore]`
- use an entirely separate DTO model for serialization (always my go-to option when serialization doesn't fit cleanly)
- use `IXmlSerializable` (ouch)
- don't use `XmlSerializer` at all (looking at LINQ-to-XML or a DOM, for example)
- use `XmlSerializer`, but edit the xml afterwards (for example via a DOM or xslt)

Answer (score 1):

the following class structure will produce the given xml

```
[XmlRoot("test")]
public class Test {
    [XmlElement("items")]
    public MyListWrapper Items {get;set;}
}

public class MyListWrapper {
    [XmlAttribute("Search")]
    public string Attribute1 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<MyItem> Items {get;set;}
}
public class MyItem {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and the xml would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<test>
   <items search="hello">
      <item id="1" />
      <item id="2" />
      <item id="3" />
   </items>
</test>
```

Comment: it will change structure of class

Comment: Also, that is not the same xml structure shown in the question